# How to Import CSV, Read a Column for Part of its Cell Data Up to a Specific Set of Characters, then Search Folders for Matching Names and Rename Them

Tags: powershell, csv, directory

I have reached the upper limit of my current knowledge. I need to import a CSV file, read two columns, match part of a cell's data in column3, search a file server at a specific folder depth (four levels down) for any subfolders whose name partially matches the partial cell data from column3, and then rename the folder using partial cell data from column1.

My current script is shown below. It works great as long as I know the data is 10 characters in length. Where it breaks is when the data is 9 characters or has a space, in which case it doesn't make a match and skips renaming folders based on those values not matching the hard-coded 10 characters.

What I would prefer to do since the data in column3 has a similar naming convention is read the cell data in column3 up to the point of " - " (space, hyphen, space) and then it could rename folders based on whatever comes before that set of characters rather than trying to always match X characters.

An example of the csv data would look like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0123-000001 |  | 1234567890 - Some Additional Text |
| 0234-000002 |  | 123456789 - Some Additional Text |
| 0567-000003 |  | 12345 678 - Some Additional Text |

Current Script:

```
$folderPath = "\\server\share\*\*\*\*"
$csvPath = "C:\pathtolocalfile\localfile.csv"

$csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

foreach ($row in $csvData)
{
    $partialCellData = $row.Column3.Substring(0, 10)
    $prepend = $row.Column1.Substring(5, 6)
    $subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Directory

    foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders)
    {
        if ($subfolder.Name -like "*$partialCellData*")
        {
            $newName = "("+ $prepend + ") " + $subfolder.Name
            Rename-Item -Path $subfolder.FullName -NewName $newName
        }
    }
}
```

And the final result on the file server would look something like this:

| Folders |
| --- |
| 02382_1234567890_3932 |
| 123456789_6878 |
| I_LIKE_PIE_12345 678_5200 |

***Renamed to***

| Folders |
| --- |
| (000001) 02382_1234567890_3932 |
| (000002) 123456789_6878 |
| (000003) I_LIKE_PIE_12345 678_5200 |

Comment: `('1234567890 - Some Additional Text' -split ' - ')[0]` extracts the the text before " - "

Comment: ..and `('0123-000001' -split '-')[-1]` gives you the `$prepend` number from column1

Comment: Sure enough, it took some doing but the final result is $prefix = ($row.Column3 -split ' - ')[0] and then $prepend = ($row.Column1 -split '-')[-1]. Thanks to both mklement0 and Theo for making me think a bit deeper about it.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @NowhereAtoll. I suggest writing the solution up as an answer, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

If your values before the '-' are always numeric then you could use Regex,

```
$folderPath = "\\server\share\*\*\*\*"
$csvPath = "C:\pathtolocalfile\localfile.csv"

$csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

foreach ($row in $csvData) {
    $partialCellData = [regex]::Match($row.Column3, "\d+\s\d+|\d+").Groups[0].Value
    $prepend = [regex]::Match($row.Column1, "(\d{4})-(\d{6})").Groups[2].Value
    $subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Directory

    foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) {
        if ($subfolder.Name -match $partialCellData)
        {
            $newName = "("+ $prepend + ") " + $subfolder.Name
            Rename-Item -Path $subfolder.FullName -NewName $newName
        }
    }
}
```